# UITableView with source: Array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am building a UITableView that has as source an Array of Dictionaries.
Each dictionary has a letter as key, and an array of contacts as value, for example: Key "A" - Value "Adam, Alex, Andreas".
My problem now is that I can't get the correct number of rows per section, or the section title... 
By they way, I am new to Objective-C so I'm sorry if my question seems odd.
Some guidance would be very much appreciated!

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //tableContent is my array of dictionaries
    return [self.tableContent count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //here I don't know how to get the dictionary value array length that would be the
    //the number of contacts per letter
    return ?
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    //here I don't know how to get the dictionary key to set as section title
    retrun ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be wrapping your data in an array for no reason. If your data was simply a dictionary it would be easier for you

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *tableContent;

...

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return [self.tableContent count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  NSString *key = [self tableView:nil titleForHeaderInSection:section];
  return [[self.tableContent objectForKey:key] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
  return [[self sortedKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sortedKeys;
{
  return [self.tableContent.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```

Comment: That is indeed very true... I'll try this and simplify the data structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I read that, it seems that each dictionary only has one key (and a matching array). If so, get the dictionary that is in `self.tableContent` at the section offset.  For `numberOfRowsInSection:` return the number of objects in the contacts array and for `titleForHeaderInSection:` return the key.  Getting `allValues` and `allKeys` from the dictionary may make it simpler than trying to keep track of **which** key is in each dictionary.

(It would also probably be easier if you had an array of custom objects rather than dictionaries.  Then, each object could have a title property and a contacts array property.)